# PHP - PHPBBB 3.1.1 style installation on Ubuntu 14.04

Tags: styles, installation, admin, phpbb3

According to the guides I've been reading it should be really easy - Just drag the Style folder which contains imageset,template,theme and style.cfg inside /var/www/html/styles and go to ACP and I should be able to see it in Customise > Styles or Customise > Install Styles.

However, Even that I uploaded 5 styles to the folder ACP does not show me any of them to install. Anybody has any ideas about this issue or solved it yet?

Thank you.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Make sure your styles are for 3.1.x as the older 3.0.x styles are not compatible

Comment: Thank you. I did not know that. Also, It seems like there are literally no styles for 3.1 version. Better to use 3.0.